# GNUGetText memory leak on Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

I am using GNUGetText to translate my app.
Just installed Eurekalog to check any memory leak and make sure the app runs clearly.
Each time I close the app I get bunch of possible memory leaks, here follows one:

```
|+Leak #3: Type=BSTR (Memory): $058A0A24 - SysReAllocStringLen; Count=1                                                                                                    |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|00000002|04     |00000000|00825A8F|myapp.exe|00425A8F|LcUnit                 |TGnuGettextInstance             |dgettext                                  |1564[7]  |
|00000002|04     |00000000|00823BBD|myapp.exe|00423BBD|LcUnit                 |                                |dgettext                                  |737[1]   |
|00000002|04     |00000000|008239FF|myapp.exe|004239FF|LcUnit                 |                                |ResourceStringGettext                     |658[10]  |
|00000002|04     |00000000|00827E65|myapp.exe|00427E65|LcUnit                 |TGnuGettextInstance             |LoadResString                             |2484[45] |
|00000002|04     |00000000|00824407|myapp.exe|00424407|LcUnit                 |                                |LoadResStringW                            |1054[1]  |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00A01931|myapp.exe|00601931|cxClasses              |                                |cxGetResourceString                       |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00B45E17|myapp.exe|00745E17|cxGridCustomView       |TcxCustomGridCellViewInfo       |CalculateParams                           |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00B4673D|myapp.exe|0074673D|cxGridCustomView       |TcxCustomGridCellViewInfo       |Calculate                                 |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00BD1471|myapp.exe|007D1471|cxGridCustomTableView  |TcxCustomGridPartViewInfo       |CalculateInvisible                        |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00B47C30|myapp.exe|00747C30|cxGridCustomView       |TcxCustomGridViewInfo           |MainCalculate                             |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00B2C438|myapp.exe|0072C438|cxGridDetailsSite      |TcxCustomGridDetailsSiteViewInfo|Calculate                                 |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00B313D6|myapp.exe|007313D6|cxGrid                 |TcxGridLayoutChange             |Execute                                   |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00B33EA9|myapp.exe|00733EA9|cxGrid                 |                                |DoFinalChanges                            |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00B33F3A|myapp.exe|00733F3A|cxGrid                 |TcxCustomGrid                   |DoUpdate                                  |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00B34286|myapp.exe|00734286|cxGrid                 |TcxCustomGrid                   |EndUpdate                                 |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00B33E9C|myapp.exe|00733E9C|cxGrid                 |                                |DoFinalChanges                            |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00B33F3A|myapp.exe|00733F3A|cxGrid                 |TcxCustomGrid                   |DoUpdate                                  |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00B34286|myapp.exe|00734286|cxGrid                 |TcxCustomGrid                   |EndUpdate                                 |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00B49C55|myapp.exe|00749C55|cxGridCustomView       |TcxCustomGridView               |GridEndUpdate                             |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|00C45821|myapp.exe|00845821|cxGridDBDataDefinitions|TcxGridDBDataController         |EndFullUpdate                             |         |
|00000002|03     |00000000|0079FDDD|myapp.exe|0039FDDD|Data.DB                |TDataLink                       |DataEvent                                 |         |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

which points to the following function:

```
function TGnuGettextInstance.dgettext(const szDomain: DomainString;
  const szMsgId: MsgIdString): TranslatedUnicodeString;
begin
  if not Enabled then begin
    {$ifdef DXGETTEXTDEBUG}
    DebugWriteln ('Translation has been disabled. Text is not being translated: '+szMsgid);
    {$endif}
    Result:=szMsgId;
  end else begin
    Result:=UTF8Decode(EnsureLineBreakInTranslatedString(getdomain(szDomain,DefaultDomainDirectory,CurLang).gettext(StripCRRawMsgId(utf8encode(szMsgId)))));

    {$ifdef DXGETTEXTDEBUG}
    if (szMsgId<>'') and (Result='') then
      DebugWriteln (Format('Error: Translation of %s was an empty string. This may never occur.',[szMsgId]));
    {$endif}
  end;
end;
```

particularly at the following line:

```
Result:=UTF8Decode(EnsureLineBreakInTranslatedString(getdomain(szDomain,DefaultDomainDirectory,CurLang).gettext(StripCRRawMsgId(utf8encode(szMsgId)))));
```

Any idea?
Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of memory leaks that show up like this are secondary; you won't find answers trying to track them down directly from this list. Look for TStringList entries where you added Objects or copied strings. Also places where you assigned something to a .Data property. You seem to be giving something to the cxGrid that's not being managed properly. It wouldn't surprise me if all of these were just from two references! I've seen a couple of dozen leak reports disappear by adding just one obj.Free call to a Finally clause.